# Kitchenaid gas stove - burner knob won't turn

Tags: gas, stove

This is a Kitchenaid two oven free standing stove with 5 burners.  (middle one is useless in my opinion.)  Anyway...

On day my right rear gas burner knob decided not to turn.  it will push in, but it won't turn to ignite. I just took it apart - the stove front- and it looks fine.  I tried spraying that particular knob with WD40 and liquid wrench.  No luck.  Any more suggestions??

If I could figure it out, can I switch the middle burner assembly with the right rear one?

Answer (score 1):

I have this same stove. When we boil water and use the large burner on high the valve gets harder to turn. When it cools down it's fine.

The valves are replaceable. It is the small valve that the knob slides into. These are prone to failure. I bought two of these valves from an online retailer.

Answer (score 0):

Before getting into the guts of  your stove try pushing in and turning the stuck  knob.   It fixed ours and we felt really silly for not figuring it out. It's sort of like the motion to open a childproof cap-- pushing and turning at the same time

Comment: I have never seen a gas stove where you don't push the knob in to be able to turn it.

Comment: Whether I push the knob in or don't it in it will not turn at all.  The other knobs work fine.